# pyspark groupBy case when

Tags: python, pyspark

given the spark dataframe(cat_sdf)

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|category     |date           |nums           |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|A            |2005-01-01     |1              |
|A            |2005-02-01     |2              |
|A            |2005-01-03     |3              |
|B            |2004-03-01     |3              |
|B            |2004-04-04     |1              |
|A            |2006-04-06     |4              |
|B            |2007-01-10     |1              |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I want to groupBy the category and year and then expand the sum of numbers of category in each month.

The result would be like

```
+-----------+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+----+--------+
|category   |year   |jan_num |feb_num  |mar_num |apr_num  | ...|dec_num |
+-----------+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+----+--------+
|A          |2005   |4       |2        |0       |0        | ...| 0      |
|A          |2006   |0       |0        |0       |4        | ...| 0      |
|B          |2004   |0       |0        |3       |1        | ...| 0      |
|B          |2007   |1       |0        |0       |0        | ...| 0      |
+-----------+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+----+--------+
```

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, year, month, sum

new_sdf = cat_sdf.groupBy('category', year('date')).agg(when(month('date') == 1, sum('nums')).alias('jan_num').\
when(month('date') == 2, sum('nums')).alias('feb_num').\
...otherwise(0)
```

But it doesn't work.

Any suggestion about how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `case when` for each month, you can `groupby` `category`, `year` and `month` then pivot months into columns

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .groupBy(
        F.col('category'),
        F.year('date').alias('year'),
        F.date_format('date', 'MM_MMMM').alias('month')
    )
    .agg(F.sum('nums').alias('nums'))

    .groupBy('category', 'year')
    .pivot('month')
    .agg(F.sum('nums').alias('nums'))
    .fillna(0)
    
    .orderBy('category', 'year')
    .show()
)

# Output
# +--------+----+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
# |category|year|01_January|02_February|03_March|04_April|
# +--------+----+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
# |       A|2005|         4|          2|       0|       0|
# |       A|2006|         0|          0|       0|       4|
# |       B|2004|         0|          0|       3|       1|
# |       B|2007|         1|          0|       0|       0|
# +--------+----+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
```